# TFS 2005 Server restore from one hardware to another

Tags: restore, team-foundation-server

i have just performed a TFS 2005 restore from a dual server setup to a different set of duel servers

after following the installation guide for TFS 2005 and following the Restoration steps

i am having problems with the reports when i access the url

http://localhost/reports ---> i can see all the data that i restored , however when to open old reports i can see that they exist however  the URL points to the OLD server.

when i change the URL link manually i get the error in the format of "GUID NUMBER - is not a valid user"

so as it seems i have two problems one being the link which did not update itself to reflect the new server 
second is the error i am getting when i attempt to access the data after changing the URL.

More info

all 4 servers are members of the same domain
i am using the same TFSSERVICE / TFSREPORTS account 
i used the same installation Account TFSSETUP .

any assistance will be welcomed here :)

thanks .

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668756.aspx#UpdateAccountIdentity